# How to write a simple hierarchical Makefile?

Tags: bash, build, makefile

Some days ago I posted an answer in stack overflow about how to write a hierarchical make (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498213/make-hierarchical-make-file). The answer was deleted, therefore I assume that it was completely wrong or off topic (or both).

I would like to know how to write hierarchical Makefile. This is a Makefile that calls several Makefiles in sub-directories. I assume a directory structure like:

```
- project
  |--module1
      |--Makefile
      |--...
  |--module2
     |--Makefile
     |--module2.1
     |--module2.2  
     |--...
  |--module3
     |--Makefile
     |--...
  |--etc
```

I also assume that the project members have only agreed only upon a minimal set of makefile targets like: all (default), clean, install, and so. So, the following commands including make flags will be propagate to the modules:

```
cd project
make clean  
make -k
make install
#etc
```

What is wrong with the following project Makefile:

```
PACKAGES = \
    module1 \
    module2 \
    emodule3

VIRTUAL_PACKAGES = $(addsuffix /.virtual.Makefile,${PACKAGES})

TARGETS=clean install all

.PHONY: $(TARGETS)
default: all

FLAGS = $(ifeq $(MAKEFLAGS) "","",-$(MAKEFLAGS))

$(TARGETS): $(VIRTUAL_PACKAGES)

$(VIRTUAL_PACKAGES): 
    $(MAKE) $(FLAGS) -C $(@D) $(MAKECMDGOALS)
```

yes, the $VIRTUAL_PACKAGES in the Makefile looks odd. The alternative of mixing a for loop is a bit shorter but I am not sure if it is better (as I need to rely on bash):
    PACKAGES = \
        module1 \
        module2 \
        emodule3

```
TARGETS=clean install all

.PHONY: $(TARGETS)
default: all

FLAGS = $(ifeq $(MAKEFLAGS) "","",-$(MAKEFLAGS))

$(TARGETS): 
    for p in $(PACKAGES) ; do $(MAKE) $(FLAGS) -C $$p $@ || break; done
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does that assignment to `FLAGS` work? Which version of Make are you using?

Comment: A non-recursive solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7321954/412080

Comment: May or may not be useful to you, but for managing complex projects I find cmake way easier. It is really easy to have a hierarchy of CMakeLists.txt. Makefiles will be generated automatically.

Comment: @Beta: 1) yes, the `FLAGS` assignment works...Why? 2) Makefile version is 3.81.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are "dragons" here.  It can be done, but the implications can be tricky.

Google, **"Recursive Make Considered Harmful"**.  You will get very good (simple) illustrations of exactly what you want (e.g., hierarchical-make), plus good explanations of the pitfalls/concerns.  Some of the "responses" will discuss possible "best-practices", and ways to mitigate problems.  Then, you can decide if the issues raised are compelling for your application or not.

The original paper:

http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/

Some other links:

http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RecursiveMakeConsideredHarmful

http://dbaspot.com/configuration-management/194597-thoughts-recursive-make-considered-harmful.html